# numeric data converted to decimal while writing SPSS pyreadstat using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing problem when we are merging 2 SPSS file using python, all numeric data converted into decimal when we are reading SPSS data file. I have tried to convert this into int64 by using panda but when trying to save merged file then it converted back to decimal.

```
import pyreadstat

import pandas as pd

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav('SWAN_p1.sav', apply_value_formats=False, disable_datetime_conversion=True, user_missing=True)

df_2, meta2 = pyreadstat.read_sav('SWAN_p2.sav', apply_value_formats=False, disable_datetime_conversion=True, user_missing=True)

frames = [pd.DataFrame(df), pd.DataFrame(df_2)]
data_final = pd.concat(frames)

c_labels = meta.column_labels

v_labels = meta.value_labels

v_type = meta.original_variable_types

measures = meta.variable_measure

storage_width = meta.variable_storage_width

variable_value_labels = meta.value_labels

variable_l = meta.variable_value_labels

pyreadstat.write_sav(data_final, "SWAN_Merged_v3.sav", variable_measure=measures, column_labels=c_labels, variable_value_labels=variable_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

SPSS has only one type of numeric data, and that one has decimal, there is no Integer type, therefore always that you save to SAV, you are converting whatever numeric data you have in pandas to decimal, and of course when you read it back it will be decimal.

What you could do is to set the display format of the variable to be F1.0 (no decimals shown), and when reading back, for those variables having such format, convert them yourself into integers.